# Process does not start on server

Tags: c#, process

I have in my controller a method called `Print` which starts a print process on my local machine. This works fine.

However, when I put this code into another pc (my server) the process does not start. I get inside of the controller and then it immediately gets returned. I don't get any 500 error message. The method returns 200/OK.

Why is the process not being started? (all paths and permissions are corrected)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Print(string guid)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["batPath"];
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


    proc.Start();
    Response.Write(proc.SessionId);
    proc.WaitForExit();

    return new JsonResult();
}
```

i would really be glad if someone tell me how to maybe debug this code. (i don't have visual studio on serv. pc)

P.S. 
Also, i want to add that process does not start in a background(different display) - i can't see it in task manager.

Comment: Are you expecting it to start the print process on your local machine? Because it won't, it's on an entirely different computer.

Comment: i expect it to run .bat file ,thats it.

Comment: I guess the bat exited very quickly. The bug is in the bat file.

Comment: if i run it manually - it works and does what i want(and not quick)

Comment: Your wrote that permissions are granted, but haven't written what permissions are those, so please double check that executing scripts is allowed for user account that Application Pool for Your application is running on.

Comment: @lukaszM hm, but i think if program would not have a permission to run a file it would crash and return 500 error ,right?

Comment: Are You using IIS when testing the code on Your local machine? According to this article: http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/10/how-to-run-bat-file-from-aspnet-in.html there can be some issues when running batch files on IIS. I also found a suggestion to assign execute permission to *cmd.exe* process for user set to be used by application pool: http://forums.asp.net/t/905351.aspx?Execute+bat+file+in+Web+Form+using+ASP+Net.

Comment: @LukaszM yes, i tested it both on VS localhost and under IIS

Comment: If You tried setting permissions to *cmd.exe* and it still doesn't work, try to install remote debugger tool. It depends on what VS version You use, but it should be available on Microsoft web sites.